# How do you concatenate multiple columns in a DataFrame into a another column when some values are null?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

`def column_concat(a,b):
    return concat(a,b)

searches_df = searches_df.withColumn('unique_id',reduce(column_concat,(searches_df[col] for col in search_parameters)))`

This works except when a column contains a null value, then the whole concatenated string is null. I'd like the a place holder or some character instead in the concatenated string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("foo", "bar"), ("baz", None)], 
                                ('a', 'b'))
df.show()

+---+----+
|  a|   b|
+---+----+
|foo| bar|
|baz|null|
+---+----+
```

One solution is to use a udf to filter/replace the null(s), e.g.:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

concat_udf = F.udf(lambda cols: "".join([x if x is not None else "*" for x in cols]), StringType())
df.withColumn("unique_id", concat_udf(F.array("a", "b"))).show()
```

which yields:

```
+---+----+---------+
|  a|   b|unique_id|
+---+----+---------+
|foo| bar|   foobar|
|baz|null|     baz*|
+---+----+---------+
```

Alternatively:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def myConcat(*cols):
    return F.concat(*[F.coalesce(c, F.lit("*")) for c in cols])

df.withColumn("unique_id", myConcat("a", "b")).show()
```

which also yields:

```
+---+----+---------+
|  a|   b|unique_id|
+---+----+---------+
|foo| bar|   foobar|
|baz|null|     baz*|
+---+----+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you! I overcome the problem by using concat_ws instead, however these solutions are useful and necessary if a placeholder is required.

Comment: Is there a way the above myconcat function written over scala.

Answer (score 3):

```
df = df.withColumn('joined_column', sf.concat(sf.col('colname1'),sf.lit('_'), sf.col('colname2')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the pyspark sql functions as below first

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
df = df.withColumn('joined_column', sf.concat(sf.col('colname1'),sf.lit('_'), sf.col('colname2')))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spark Scala, you can first fill  null values of those columns with `NA` (one can take any value) and then perform concatenate operations. It works perfectly fine.

```
df = df.na.fill("NA").concat(col A, col B, col C, col D, col E)
```